# Can I change the proof this way?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, connectedness

In the proof I think he takes intersections of forward images. I am not that comfortable with this because I remember there was some problems with that. So I change it to inverse images. Is the proof still valid then?

[image]

Comment: Yeah I think it works!

Comment: @Nameless Thank you very much!